# Can we define Affine space by Affine combination (without the vector space )?

Tags: vector-spaces, affine-geometry

The Affine space is defined with the help of vector space.

Is it possible to make Affine combination the basic operation of Affine space, to define the Affine space? so that we dont need a vector space (may still need a field) to define the Affine space.